# How to apply a DataBinder.Eval to a Text property of a HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, web-controls

I use .NET and C#.

I use a Repeater control, inside I have this code.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>"></asp:HyperLink>
```

---

ERROR:

```
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

I'm not able to DataBind the Text property for the HyperLink control.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace double quote with a single quote

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: +1 Microsoft fixed this abomination in [MVC Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) with better syntax

Comment: Can I use Razor even in ASP.net Web Forms?